# How can I close the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am have Fragment on the Activity. Fragment has button. if i click on the button, Fragment must be close. How i am did this?

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment{

    private ImageView btnApply;
    private ClickButton clickButton = new ClickButton();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info, container, false);
        btnApply = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSendItem);
        btnApply.setOnClickListener(clickButton);
        return rootView;
    }

    private class ClickButton implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (R.id.btnSendItem == v.getId()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CLOSE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `DialogFragment`. DialogFragments can be used as popups **or** as regular Fragments. And can have a close button to dismiss them (as all Dialogs).

Comment: What do you mean with `close Fragment`? You can replace it with another fragment or you can finish the `activity`.

Comment: I want that fragment. "Close" button does not interest me. I need to close it after some operations

Comment: @hrskrs I have a main Activity. This camera. When I scan a bar code, I'm showing a fragment of the data. There is a button on it. I want to when you click on it to close this piece

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no such thing like *close the fragment*, but you can **remove** the fragment from the stack. To pop the fragment use the following inside button click listener

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Comment: add and "remove" of Fragments should be managed by their parent MainActivity

Comment: where i need to enter this code in Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @VikaS you'll have to place this code on back button click inside a fragment.

Answer (score -1):

When this fragment is of type `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` then this seems to work:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

This pops the top visible fragment off the stack.